# how to access value of JSON whose key contains dot

Tags: node.js, json, express

Hello I want to access value of a key in JSON which is nested JSON

**here is my json**

```
{
  "errors": {
    "products.2.name": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "This field is required",
      "properties": {
        "message": "This field is required",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "name",
        "value": ""
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "name",
      "value": ""
    },
    "products.2.price": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "This field is required",
      "properties": {
        "message": "This field is required",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "price",
        "value": null
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "price",
      "value": null
    },
    "products.2.size": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "This field is required",
      "properties": {
        "message": "This field is required",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "size",
        "value": ""
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "size",
      "value": ""
    },
    "products.2.stock": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "This field is required",
      "properties": {
        "message": "This field is required",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "stock",
        "value": null
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "stock",
      "value": null
    },
    "products.2.unit": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "This field is required",
      "properties": {
        "message": "This field is required",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "unit",
        "value": ""
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "unit",
      "value": ""
    },
    "products.2.category": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "This field is required",
      "properties": {
        "message": "This field is required",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "category",
        "value": ""
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "category",
      "value": ""
    },
    "products.2.brand": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "This field is required",
      "properties": {
        "message": "This field is required",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "brand",
        "value": ""
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "brand",
      "value": ""
    }
  },
  "_message": "register products validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError",
  "message": "register products validation failed: products.2.name: This field is required, products.2.price: This field is required, products.2.size: This field is required, products.2.stock: This field is required, products.2.unit: This field is required, products.2.category: This field is required, products.2.brand: This field is required"
}
```

I want to display error message under input field like when user leave the text field empty I have to show the error message under the input field , for that I need to access the value of **message** inside **products.2.name**. I am trying but not able to do it and like **products.2.name** others "products.2.__"  all other field

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation).

For example:

```js
 myobject.errors["products.2.name"].message
```

Comment: Great. You can "accept" my answer if you're happy with it.

Answer (score -1):

Is this json supposed to be used by a 3rd party translation module?
If not, you can opt for
`t.errors['products.2.name']`

with t, contening all you json object

Comment: what is 3rd party translation module?

Comment: Its for displaying error message under text field of form

Comment: Vue i18n, pipe `translate` in angular or something similar.

Comment: no i am not doing that i am using handlebars

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).